# Sum of sum of factors of numbers that are < 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

Let $a, b \in (0,1)$. Given an integer $N$, how can I calculate the following sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N{\sum_{j=0}^i}a^j\cdot b^{i-j}
$$

I tried different tricks so far, but none seemed to solve it.

If it simplifies things, it is possible to consider only the limit:
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N{\sum_{j=0}^i}a^j\cdot b^{i-j}
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Write $x = \frac ab$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^N{\sum_{j=0}^i}a^j\cdot b^{i-j} &= \sum_{i=1}^Nb^i{\sum_{j=0}^i}x^j\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^Nb^i \frac{x^{i+1} - 1}{x - 1}\\
&= \frac1{x-1}\left(x\sum_{i=1}^N b^ix^i  - \sum_{i=1}^Nb^i\right),
\end{align*}
$$
and now it's a matter of evaluating geometric series, one with ratio $bx = a$ and one with ratio $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Find a close formula $f(i)$ for 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{i}a^j\cdot b^{i-j}=a^0\cdot b^i+a^1\cdot b^{i-1}+a^2\cdot b^{i-2}+...+a^i\cdot b^0$$
Note that this is a geometric series.
Then try to do the same with 
$$\sum_{j=1}^Nf(i)$$